# Apply Shannon-Weiner index to evaluate single-cell sample balance?

Tags: cell-biology, ecology, statistics, rna-sequencing

I would like to identify single-cell clusters where each sample is evenly represented in it. Is it OK to calculate the Shannon-Weiner index from the sample counting data of each cluster? I am worrying that the entire population of each sample is not balanced, therefore I plan to normalize within-cluster counts with total cell number in each cluster.

My naive idea is summarized in these formulas:

$$
E_{i} = \frac{\sum_{j=1}^{N_{sample\,}}P_{i,j}\log_2{P_{i,j}}}{E_{max}}
$$

where,

$$
P_{i,j} = \frac{C_{i,j}}{\sum_{i=1}^{N_{cluster}}} + pseudo\_count
$$

$C_{i,j}$ is the count of sample $j$ in cluster $i$.

Comment: What is the purpose of the pseudocount?

Comment: Pseudocount aside, you are proposing to estimate a rescaled Shannon entropy onto $[0,1]$ of each cluster. That is fine if that is what you want to know.

Comment: @Galen Log2P_ij  undefined if C_ij equals to zero. That is the cluster does not have any instances of the sample. Are there other approaches to avoid this?

Comment: That's quite understandable, however by convention we take the right-limiting value $H(0) \triangleq \lim_{p \rightarrow 0^+} p \log_2(p) = 0$.